How to parse a .blk text file into a dictionary?
I have a readable block file (.blk) that is converted to a .txt file (from War Thunder). I'd like to parse the contents so that they are easy to access in my Python script.
Here's a snippet from such a block file:
areas{
  spawn_zone{
    type:t="Sphere"
    tm:m=[[9.70537, 0, 0] [0, 9.70537, 0] [0, 0, 9.70537] [2881.52, 75.8896, 182.321]]
    objLayer:i=0

    props{}
  }
}

How can I parse it so that I can access the different parts in my script? The goal is to be able to type something along the lines of areas.spawn_zone.type and it would return "Sphere".
A block file has a lot of clauses but they are identifiable by name (areas{...}, units{...} etc.), so it needs to account for that.

you have to write a parser for it, or use one that already exists. What, exactly, is this format?

Since it doesn't look like a standard data format (it's not JSON, YAML, etc.) it would be important to know exactly what needs to be possible in this format. Do you know if these blocks can be nested further? Are there other types than :t, :m, and :i? It would be easier to help if you had a look through more of these files and collected all the variations you need to code for

It's a format that is to my knowledge unique to the game War Thunder. The files are used by the game to read information when loading user-made missions and other modded content. It is "readable" to encourage said mission-making and modding, thus can be easilt converted and edited. Downside is that it's an uncommon format.

This is some documentation that should help putting a parser together: https://wiki.warthunder.com/Block_file_(.BLK) - it's not complete though, since it seems to be missing the :m (matrix?) format

@Grismar for what is currently my goal, all types can be disregarded as I will only be using the :t (text) type anyways.
The snippet I posted is just a snippet. The file I have on hand is roughly 2500 lines, but follows the same structure.

If you want a cool project, build a parser using something like: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#steps-to-follow for this format. People in the War thunder community might appreciate it.

Based on the documentation available and the example you gave, a plain Python parser for .blk file from the War Thunder game might look like this:
EXAMPLE = """
areas{
  spawn_zone{
    type:t="Sphere"
    tm:m=[[9.7053, 0, 0] [0, 9.7053, 0] [0, 0, 9.7053] [2881.52, 75.8896, 182.321]]
    objLayer:i=0
    height:r=0.25
    line{ line:p4=115, +10000, 117, 0; move:b=no; thousandth:b=yes; }
  }
}
"""


def parse_blk(data: str, start: int = 0) -> (dict, int):
    from enum import Enum
    from itertools import islice
    from re import findall

    class States(Enum):
        ID_NEXT = 1
        ID = 2
        BLOCK_NEXT = 3
        TYPE_NEXT = 4
        TYPE = 5
        EQUALS_NEXT = 6
        VALUE_NEXT = 7
        VALUE = 8

    def unexpected():
        raise SyntaxError(f'Unexpected character #{i}: {ch}')

    def matrix(m: str) -> list | float:
        m = m.strip()

        if not m.startswith('[') or not m.endswith(']'):
            xs = m.split(',')
            if len(xs) > 1:
                return [matrix(v) for v in xs]
            try:
                v = float(m)
                return v
            except ValueError:
                raise SyntaxError(f'Invalid matrix format {s}')

        m = m[1:-1]
        return [matrix(v) for v in findall(r'\[([^]]+)]', m)]

    state = States.ID_NEXT
    s = ''
    _id = ''
    _type = ''
    result = {}
    enum_data = iter(enumerate(data))
    next(islice(enum_data, start, start), None)
    for i, ch in enum_data:
        match state:
            case States.ID_NEXT:
                if ch.isalpha() or ch == '_':
                    s = ch
                    state = States.ID
                elif ch.isspace():
                    pass
                elif ch == '}':
                    return result, i
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.ID:
                if ch == ':':
                    _id = s
                    state = States.TYPE_NEXT
                elif ch.isspace():
                    _id = s
                    state = States.BLOCK_NEXT
                elif ch.isalpha() or ch == '_':
                    s += ch
                elif ch == '{':
                    _id = s
                    result[_id], n = parse_blk(data, i + 1)
                    next(islice(enum_data, n, n), None)
                    state = States.ID_NEXT
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.BLOCK_NEXT:
                if ch == '{':
                    result[_id], n = parse_blk(data, i + 1)
                    next(islice(enum_data, n, n), None)
                    state = States.ID_NEXT
                elif ch.isspace():
                    pass
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.TYPE_NEXT:
                if ch.isalpha():
                    s = ch
                    state = States.TYPE
                elif ch.isspace():
                    pass
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.TYPE:
                if ch.isalnum():
                    s += ch
                elif ch == '=':
                    _type = s
                    if _type not in ['i', 'r', 't', 'b', 'm', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']:
                        raise ValueError(f'Unknown type {_type}')
                    state = States.VALUE_NEXT
                elif ch.isspace():
                    _type = s
                    state = States.EQUALS_NEXT
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.EQUALS_NEXT:
                if ch == '=':
                    state = States.VALUE_NEXT
                elif ch.isspace():
                    pass
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.VALUE_NEXT:
                if ch.isalnum() or ch in '"[+-':
                    s = ch
                    state = States.VALUE
                elif ch.isspace():
                    pass
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case States.VALUE:
                if ch in [';', '\n']:
                    state = States.ID_NEXT
                    result[_id] = s
                    match _type:
                        case 'i':
                            result[_id] = int(s)
                        case 'r':
                            result[_id] = float(s)
                        case 't':
                            result[_id] = s
                        case 'b':
                            if s not in ['yes', 'true', 'no', 'false']:
                                raise ValueError(f'Unknown boolean value {s}')
                            result[_id] = s in ['yes', 'true']
                        case 'm':
                            result[_id] = matrix(s)
                        case 'p2' | 'p3' | 'p4':
                            result[_id] = tuple(float(v) for v in s.split(','))
                            if (r := len(result[_id])) != (e := int(_type[1])):
                                raise ValueError(
                                    f'Expected {e} values, got {r}')
                        case '_':
                            raise SyntaxError(f'Unknown type {_type}')
                elif ch.isalnum() or ch.isspace() or ch in '_"[].,+-':
                    s += ch
                elif ch == '}':
                    result[_id] = s
                    return result, i
                else:
                    unexpected()
            case _:
                raise SyntaxError(f'Unknown state {state}')
    return result, len(data)


# the function returns both the dictionary and the number of characters parsed
parsed, _ = parse_blk(EXAMPLE)
print(parsed)
print(parsed['areas']['spawn_zone']['type'])

The output:
{'areas': {'spawn_zone': {'type': '"Sphere"', 'tm': [[9.7053, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 9.7053, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.7053], [2881.52, 75.8896, 182.321]], 'objLayer': 0, 'height': 0.25, 'line': {'line': (115.0, 10000.0, 117.0, 0.0), 'move': False, 'thousandth': True}}}}
"Sphere"

Note that I added some data to the example to show the other types documented for the format - I know you don't need all of them, but someone else may be looking to read .blk files from War Thunder with Python as well.
Note that I named _id and _type with an underscore because using id and type would shadow keywords, but I feel those are the appropriate names to use here, so I used the underscore versions. You could name them key and t, if you don't like that.
And in case you're wondering - an LLM like ChatGPT doesn't do great on parsing a file like this, although it would allow you to solve the specific problem you wanted solved quite well. But I do use GitHub CoPilot in my editor, so writing a parser like this is actually not a lot of work - it pretty much writes itself if you guide it in the right direction.

Seems to work for the most part, but I'm having trouble with the " symbol. Is it possible to remove the "-symbols that contain a string?
e.g remove the " in type:t="Sphere".

It was unclear if the value of type:t was '"Sphere"' or 'Sphere', so I kept it simple. But of course you could change result[_id] = s to result[_id] = s[1:-1] for case 't':. Thing is,  there may be other small issues like this. For example, the code assumes a newline or semicolon character terminates a value - it's possible that these inside a text value should be considered part of the text, which would require separate parsing for text values. It's also unclear how quotes inside text would be escaped. As I indicated in the comments, you'd need a more complete example to be sure.

I figured out the problem. I added more stuff to allow for all the weird structure-choices that is in these files. I can make a repository on github with the parser if you'd like to see what I changed. Thank you so much for the "template" that you provided, saved me a lot of trouble.

If you don't mind sharing, putting the code on GitHub and sharing a link to the repo here in the comments may be helpful to anyone looking for a way to parse a .blk and finding this on SO.

GitHub repo:
https://github.com/isaacweihs/blk_parser
